# How to bind json array data to chart.js with same canvas id?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays, json, chart.js

My HTML Canvas is like below :

```
<div>
    <canvas id="chartdiv" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Following is the json data,

```
[{
    "SID": "1",
    "NAME": "niten",
    "FTEPERCENT": "71.29",
    "FTCPERCENT": "28.71"
}, {
    "SID": "2",
    "NAME": "jiten",
    "FTEPERCENT": "82.08",
    "FTCPERCENT": "17.92"
}]
```

And below is the enter code :

```
window.onload = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ViewDirectManagersOverviewDetails.aspx/GetEmployeeOverviewDetailsForDirectManagers",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(Result) {
            debugger;
            Result = JSON.parse(Result.d);
            var newctx1;
            for (var i = 0; i < Result.length; i++) {

                var data1 = parseFloat(Result[i].FTEPERCENT);
                var data2 = parseFloat(Result[i].FTCPERCENT);
                var tempData = {
                    labels: ["FTE", "FTC"],
                    datasets: [{
                        data: [data1, data2],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            "#FF6384",
                            "#36A2EB"
                        ],
                        hoverBackgroundColor: [
                            "#FF6384",
                            "#36A2EB"
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 5
                    }]
                };
                // For a pie chart1
                var ctx = document.getElementById("chartdiv").getContext("2d");
                var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: "pie",
                    data: tempData,
                    options: options,
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Employee Overview',
                        fontStyle: 'bold',
                        fontSize: 20
                    }
                });
            }
            $('chartdiv').append(newctx1);
        }
    });
};
```

The above code is plotting pie chart on same canvas id but I want to plot to separate pie charts since json has two array objects but canvas id should be same.

Looping through json will give two separate objects so I will have to draw in table two separate pie chart the way we show data in datatable similarly need to show pie charts in table rows.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to render multiple charts within a single canvas.  Chart.js binds to the entire canvas object and uses the full canvas to render a single chart.

If you want to see two separate pie charts then you need two separate canvas elements.  However, you can of course add multiple datasets to a single graph if that suites your needs.  For the pie chart it will embed a smaller pie chart within a larger one.

Here is an example config that shows how to setup multiple datasets in a single pie chart.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var myPie = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
        labels: ["FTE", "FTC"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: data1,
      backgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB"
      ],
      borderWidth: 5,
    }, {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: data2,
      backgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB"
      ],
      hoverBackgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#36A2EB"
      ],
      borderWidth: 5,
    }],
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Employee Overview',
      fontStyle: 'bold',
      fontSize: 20
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/RpjOWZ) to demonstrate this.

Comment: Is there any other pie charts which are open sorce and free with which we can achieve this?

Comment: Not one that renders multiple in a canvas. Why do you need this though? Why not have 2 charts using 2 different canvas elements?

Comment: Basically, i am getting datatable with multiple rows containing SID and their related data. I have taken html table to render those data iterating through row and display chart for diffrent sid in the same table multiple times. Hope you understood!!!

Comment: Why not just put a different `<canvas>` element (with a unique `id`) in each table row (inside a `<td>`)?

Comment: I am generating diffrent canvas elemnet id like  "var series = new Array(_tempCanvas.push($('<canvas/>', { id: i, width: 1, height: 1 })));"    But how to put in each table row column is where i am stuck. Can you help me writing that logic.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you are wanting vs. why it won't work, but I can update my answer with an example of many charts within a table (one per row). Is that what you are wanting to know?